# Lorentz Invariance of kinetic terms for Weyl Spinors

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

Just to preface things, this exact question has been asked before [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/521205/), but I don't feel like the answer really clarifies things for me.

The core issue is that we want to construct a 4-vector that we can contract with $\partial_\mu$ to form a Lorentz invariant kinematic term we can introduce in the Lagrangian. Schwartz finds that, for a right-handed Weyl spinor,

$$
V^\mu_R =\ \left(\psi^\dagger_R\psi_R,\psi^\dagger_R\sigma^i\psi_R\right)
$$

transforms like a 4-vector. Clearly this means that $\partial_\mu V^\mu_R$ is Lorentz invariant, but this isn't useful because a total derivative makes no meaningful contribution to the Lagrangian. Schwartz then claims that the fact that $V^\mu_R$ transforms like a 4-vector **must** mean that

$$
\psi_R^\dagger\partial_t\psi_R+\psi^\dagger_R\partial_j\sigma^j\psi_R
$$

is also Lorentz invariant. This isn't at all obvious to me, for example, in principle, why couldn't, the terms in parenthesis from the following product rule

$$
\partial_\mu V^\mu_R = \left(\psi_R^\dagger\partial_t\psi_R+\psi^\dagger_R\partial_j\sigma^j\psi_R\right)+\left(\partial_t(\psi_R^\dagger)\psi_R+\partial_j(\psi_R^\dagger)\sigma^j\psi_R\right)
$$

transform oppositely such that $\partial_\mu V^\mu_R$ remains invariant? That is, why must each individual term above be invariant?

To further clarify, the reason why the answer from the post I linked doesn't help me is because helicity has not yet been introduced. In principle there should be a self contained way of understanding this.

Comment: Just write down the Lorentz generators and work it out.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I get that that works, but the way Schwartz phrases it, it sounds like it should be an immediate consequence of the fact that $V^\mu_R$ is a 4-vector. This is what bothers me.

Comment: I suggest you read the original in Weyl's "Group theory and Quantum mechanics" His account is just so neat!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a yes or no question. Namely whether Schwarz gave a proper explanation. I vote no.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Yeah I guess that's fair. Maybe I'm looking for a formal justification where there isn't one...